# Running Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 headless on Raspberry Pi 4 8Gb

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I want to be able to use a Ubuntu desktop on my Raspberry Pi 4 8Gb.  I also want to be able to access that desktop remotely using a tool like VNCViewer.

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.10. I am unable to access the desktop remotely. I have setup SSH so I can access via text (PUTTY).  I can find no vnc capability for example.

Is it possible to do what I want?

When will vnc be available on Ubuntu 20.10 on ARM64 hardware of Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0):

Install x11vnc to access the default desktop.  However, if there is no physical monitor connected to the Pi the desktop won't start.  A work around is to connect an HDMI dummy adapter to make the Pi think there is a monitor connected.